# ServiceNow on Samsung TV

Tags: javascript, servicenow

My employer has recently purchased several Samsung Tv's to displey 'Service Now' Dashboards to teams in Applicaiton and Infrastructure Support. (not sure of model, but will be new within last 12 months)

We are able to load the relevant dashboard onto the TV using the in built web browswer, but unlike other devices, the TV doesnt automatically update the data, it requires a manual refresh.

I am wondering if there is a way to get this to auto update as it does on every other device I ave tried? On my Laptop/Pc's it updates fine, on my Samsung phone (using Samsung browser) it works fine and updates automatically.

I had thought maybe Javascript was disabled on the TV, but have checked and it is fine.

I don't want to have to cast to it. It is possible to connect wirelessly, but it would require 3 people having to connect each day just to display the information for a 24 hour period.

Any help would be appreciated. Many Thanks
MB

Comment: There might be a better solution for this, but if it's running the android OS you should be able to install a different browser (Chrome, Firefox) and see if it works on those. (I'm assuming Service Now is just a website)

Comment: @markie1611 You stated that Javascript is available in the TVs browser. Did you also check that all technologies you are using are available in the browser as well? How do you try to update the data?XmlHttpRequests? Fetch?

Comment: George - ServiceNow is just a website, but there is no ability to add another web browser. Based on what others have said in samsung forums and other places, you can not get another browser and have to use the one given.

Comment: @Fitzi - I don't know how to chek that. I have checked other services which have live reporting (google analytics) and that works fine, updating automatically. The ServiceNow page works and looks fine, just doesnt update to real-time stats.

Comment: @markie1611 I just realized that you display an external service. My inital assumption was that you display a self made dashboard, i'm sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Are you logged in as the same user on the Samsung TV's as you're testing on the other devices?

From my understanding for the dashboard widgets to auto-refresh, each of them has to be built with this capability (and not all of them have been).

Homepages however have the ability built into them to auto-refresh the whole page
https://hi.service-now.com/kb_view.do?sysparm_article=KB0634955

You could switch your dashboards to homepages (/home.do) on the Samsung displays if this refreshing behaviour is important.

Another solution would be to build a UI Page with an iframe that takes up the entire screen. In this UI Page, point it at the dashboard, and just have some simple javascript to trigger a refresh on the iframe at a predetermined interval (e.g. 5 minutes).

You just need to execute this code to trigger a refresh:
`document.getElementById('yourDashboardIframe').contentWindow.location.reload();`